# How do I add rows/columns to a matrix in ilnumerics?

Tags: matrix, ilnumerics

In Matlab this takes my two 1x102 variables (in1 and in2) and makes one that's 2x102 (out).

---

```
out = [in1 in2]
```

---

When I try this in VB/ILnumerics - with two well-formed 1x102 inputs - the output is 2x1 with both values being 0.

I'm doing it in VB like this:

---

```
Dim out As ILArray(Of Double) = {in1, in2}
```

---

It feels like I might have to extract all of the values, put them in double arrays, and pass those back in to get the results I want. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have theses options:

```
in1.concat(in2,1); 
ILMath.horzcat(in1,in2);
```

There is also `ILMath.vertcat<T>(a,b)` available.

General ILArray documentation: http://ilnumerics.net/Arrays.html

Comment: Thanks! That works! Quick notes: concat isn't in ILMath and to get the results I was looking for, above, that would be "= in1.concat(in2,0)"

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer. BTW: the SO way of saying 'thanks' is upvoting and marking as answer ;)

Comment: Well... I can't upvote or mark as an answer until I get some more street cred. Sorry! But, really, thanks for the help!